# Create 2 publicIPs and assign to nics

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to create 2 public ips and then assign one each to nics

```
for($i=1; $i -lt 3; $i++)
{

    New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name "publicIP$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic

    New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "nic$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId "publicIP$i.Id" -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id


}
```

I want to assign the output of `new-azPublicIpAddress` to a variable and then use that variable's id to assign to `-pulicIpAddressId`.

like this `$pip$i = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name "publicIP$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic` but this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>You cannot set a variable with a '$' inside it.</del>

<del>The following is a correct sample. 

    $pip = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name "publicIP$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic</del>

Considering your requirement, I suggest you use an array:

```
$pipArr = New-Object 'Object[]' 2;
$nicArr = New-Object 'Object[]' 2;
for($i=0; $i -lt 2; $i++)
{
    $pipArr[$i] = New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name "publicIP$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
    $nicArr[$i] = New-AzNetworkInterface -Name "nic$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourcegroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pipArr[$i].Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id
}
```

In this way, you can get your first public IP with "$pipArr[0]". As it is an array, you can use index with it.

Comment: `You cannot set a variable with a '$' inside it.` - huh?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Maybe you can? - :)

Comment: @4c74356b41 That is great.  Please share a new answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Jack requested, here's another way of doing the same is the following:

```
Set-Variable "pip$i" -Value (New-AzPublicIpAddress -Name "publicIP$i" -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic)
```

then you can use `Get-Variable` to get data from the variable:

```
Get-Variable "pip$i" | Select -ExpandProperty Value
```

If you just want to have `$` inside the variable you can do this:

```
${pip$i} = something
```

this will instanciate new variable with the name `pip$i`, and you could retrieve it similarly as well:

```
Do-something -Input ${pip$i}
```

Comment: Elegant answer.

Comment: i think your answer makes more sense in the context of the question, but that statement is just plain wrong ;) i suggest you remove it

Comment: Removed as suggested. :)